# Referencing an MSBuild property using the contents of another property

Tags: msbuild

I want to be able to reference an MSBuild (3) property using the contents of another property. For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SelectVariable>Test</SelectVariable>
    <TestVariable>1</TestVariable>
    <FullVariable>2</FullVariable>
</PropertyGroup>

<Message Text="Value $($(SelectVariable)Variable)"/>
```

In this scenario, I want the contents of TestVariable outputted (1). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that is possible.  However, you could achieve a similar effect with ItemGroups:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SelectVariable>Test</SelectVariable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Variable Include="1">
        <Select>Test</Select>
    </Variable>
    <Variable Include="2">
        <Select>Full</Select>
    </Variable>
</ItemGroup>

<Message Text="@(Variable)"
         Condition=" '%(Select)' == '$(SelectVariable)' " />
```

It's a little clunky tho...

Answer (score 2):

Sure this is possible. Just do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SelectVariable>Test</SelectVariable>
    <TestVariable>1</TestVariable>
    <FullVariable>2</FullVariable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Demo01">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Value>$(SelectVariable)Variable</Value>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Value $(Value)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The result is shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Doh!  Slaps head.  Shoulda seen that one!

Comment: I don't think that's what vicjugador wants. I think he wants some kind of reflexion. In your example he wants to output the value of TestVariable (1) and not the name (TestVariable). And I don't think it's possible because it would need several passes to interpretate the file...

Comment: Benjamin is correct .. the output that I want is the contents of TestVariable (1) .. and not the name of TestVariable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`<Choose>` task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164282(v=VS.85).aspx) to achieve something similar, but (as [Peter said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990476/referencing-an-msbuild-property-using-the-contents-of-another-property/3998492#3998492)) that's likely to be some distance from your desire to have something short and pithy.

Perhaps [psake](http://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake) is the answer - it has no such arbitrary and puny limits when nesting expressions and parentheses :P

Comment: I think the Choose task is the answer here.